# futures.ThreadPoolExecutor Exceptions

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm implementing `futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` and would like to change the broad `Exception` to specific exceptions (e.g. `ValueError`). Using the example below should I add the exceptions generated by `load_url` instead of the broad `Exception`? which Exceptions this section of code is referring to.

Using [this](http://masnun.com/2016/03/29/python-a-quick-introduction-to-the-concurrent-futures-module.html) page as reference:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    if not url:
       raise ValueError('Invalid URL')
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```